# Date format comparmission

Tags: regex

I have question. I am trying to prepare date regex comparmission. The problem is month and day if its one digit it can be present as 03 or 3 for both month and day. For instance possible values:

```
2015/03/27 or 2015/4/12 or 2015/07/05 or 2015/2/2 or 2015/02/3
```

What i did so far is:

```
^(?<Month>\d(0([0-1]|1[0-2])|([1-12])){1,2})/(?<Day>\d{1,2})/(?<Year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))$
```

I started to make now for month:

```
(?<Month>\d(0([0-1]|1[0-2])|([1-12])){1,2})

(0([0-1]|1[0-2])|([1-12])){1,2})
```

**so {1,2} -** because can be one digit or two for instance (12, 2, 02)

**0([0-1]|1[0-2]) | ([1-12]))** - because can be two digits or one

somehow i cant figure it into the final version.
Can you help me out?

Comment: (`[1-12]` is the same as `[12]`.) I'm not sure what you're trying to do, or what the actual problem is, but how about `/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/`? It will match `1`–`12` and `01`–`12`.

Comment: To expand @biffen comment: `[1-12]` means "any character in the range from `1` to `1`, or the character `2`".

Comment: ...but *validation* should be left to a datetime library anyway, so perhaps a better regex is `/\d{1,4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}/`. (I note the order of the parts differ between the examples and the regex.)

Answer (score 0):

Using just `\d`, you might end up with fake dates, like `12/67/4567`.
Also, your input has another date format: `Year/Month/Day`.

I suggest using this regex for your input format:

```
^(?<Year>(?:19|20)\d{2})\/(?<Month>0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(?<Day>3[01]|0?[1-9]|[12][0-9])$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qU0lW8/3)

Optional `0`s are made possible due to the `?` quantifier after `0`.

If it is for .NET, you do not have to escape `/`s.

To validate the date, use the classes and methods of the programming environment you are using. Here is an example in C#:

```
var resultFromRegex = "2015/03/27";
DateTime validDate;
var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(resultFromRegex, "yyyy/MM/dd", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out validDate);
```

Comment: This will still match *some* invalid dates, e.g. `2015/02/31`. Sooner or later one will want to run it through ‘proper’ validation anyway. (And quite the assumption leaving out all but two centuries.)

Comment: @Biffen: you are right, I agree that *validation* must be done with something like `DateTime.TryParse` or other `DateTime` methods (depending on the language of course). Using this regex will at least filter out the most obvious false positives.