# Check if numbers are present and in particular pattern using regex

Tags: regex

I want to check if a string contains digits in the format `dddd-dd-dd`. I'm not interested in checking valid dates.

**Examples:**

- Input: `att_token_2015-09-02`

  Expected output: True
- Input: `att_token_1234-99-99`

  Expected output: True
- Input: `att_token_1234`

  Expected output: False

**EDIT:** I haven't tried this in any program. I just want the regex pattern for it.

```
(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)
```

This is what I have tried so far and it returns me the numbers but I do not know if this is right.

Comment: Post your attempts to achieve this.

Comment: What is your question? What language are you using? Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: How is this question unclear to anyone ?? I'm asking for the regex pattern to match this.

Comment: The regex you have is good to go. Just check with [`date_parse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) if the return value is not FALSE, and you are done (this is for PHP, you need to use one for your programming language). And the reason for downvotes is simple: validating datetime values is veeery frequent issue on SO, you should really search a bit, and you will find tons of solutions.

Comment: The question isn't unclear, Stack Overflow is just full of people that would rather downvote an easy question because you could have looked harder for an answer than to just answer the question.

Comment: Hi there. I'm not a downvoter, nor a closevoter, however: what's unclear to me is whether you just want to check if there are some digits in the format dddd-dd-dd, or if you want to check whether there is a valid date. Given `att_token_1234-99-99`, what should the output be?

Comment: Another question weak point: no programming language is specified. That is not how a regex question should be asked, and it is clearly written in the regex tag description.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini That isn't my requirement else I would have specified in my question as to I need it to be validated as a date. I just wanted the digits.

Comment: @stribizhev Aren't regexes not dependent on the language used ?

Comment: They are, that is why it is important to indicate the language as a question tag.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no programming language is indicated while it is a requirement for regex questions.

Comment: @stribizhev I did NOT want the date validation, else I would have mentioned it in my question. My question stated that I want to see if the string contains the digits in that particular format for which I have received an answer. I was being asked questions irrelevant to my actual question for no reason.

Comment: The only thing I missed was the language since I thought regex work irrespective of language. Even then 5 down votes and 3 close requests are a little too harsh I would say.

Comment: I relived mine, but I think you will agree you did not put enough effort into it. Even if you need a regex for that: there are tons of them here and all over the place. Just type `[regex] date`, and you are bound to find some. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123524/date-format-comparmission/30123756#30123756) [are](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29233721/3832970) some of my [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30778800/3832970).

Comment: @stribizhev It is still NOT about the date. The title of my question is 'Check if number is present and in particular pattern.' Anyway thanks :)

Comment: Yes, posting a clear question with your own efforts, comprehensive examples and expected output is key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` will match digits in the yyyy-mm-dd pattern, but it won't match *dates* - it would, for instance, match 1234-99-99. You can access the match in whatever language you are using and try to do date parsing on the match to see if it's a date.

You were using `\d+` in your example, which would match something like 33-3333333-333, which is not a date.

If you are worried about a string like `123456-12-1234567` matching when they shouldn't, you can use negative lookarounds:

`(?<!\d)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?!\d)`

See example in action: https://regex101.com/r/nR0hB2/1

Comment: Well, I do not agree that `\d+` matches `33-3333333-333`, and I'd mention that `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` will find a match even in `122143245-32-321312`.

Comment: @stribizhev I meant the original example, `(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)` which uses `\d+` would match that string. Also, the OP has the date string interleaved with other data and doesn't provide context about what might be around it.

Comment: I should have posted a random number instead of my actual input. That would've removed all the confusions. I did not want the date validation else I would have specified it in the question. I just wanted to know how to check if the digits are in that particular format.

Comment: I just needed the {4} part . I think I lost 10 points from my rep for something stupid ! :(

Comment: @DevonParsons will this match exactly 4,2 and 2 digits or less than or more than the digits specified ?

Comment: @ViChU: Now, yes. `(?<!\d)\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?!\d)` contains the look-arounds that will ensure the match only if the string is not enclosed with digits.

Comment: @ViChU It'll match exactly 4 or 2 digits, but if those digits are at the very start/end of the match and there are MORE digits before/after the match, they will be ignored when you might have wanted them to prevent the match from being found. See the updated answer.

Comment: @DevonParsons Yes this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks man :)